# Wagtail - Set content_panels for specific StreamField

Tags: python, wagtail

I wanted my users to be able to define a columnar layouts in the wagtail freeform editor.

To do that I have created a stream block as follows:

```
class ColumnSplitBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    class Meta:
        template = "common/column_split_block.html"
        icon = "grip"
        label = _("Columns")
        min_num = 1
        max_num = 2
```

and then I've plugged it into my Page's Streamfield:

```
class NewsDetailPage(Page):
    template = "news/news_detail_page.html"
    parent_page_types = ['news.NewsListPage']

    content = StreamField([
        ("rich_text", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ("image", blocks.ImageBlock()),
        ("column_split", blocks.ColumnSplitBlock(
            [
                ("rich_text", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
                ("image", ImageChooserBlock()),
            ]
        )),
    ], verbose_name=_("Content"))

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel("content"),
    ]
```

However, **I'd like to customize the display of ColumnSplitBlock inside the StreamBlock**.

In particular I wanted to use [FieldRowPanel](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html#fieldrowpanel) to create as mentioned the columnar layout in the admin editor. Is that even possible?